# Compensation by the residue of the zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

(Repost of a question from MSE, where it found no success)

Let $F$ be a global number field. Introduce a local quantity at every place
$$x_p = \frac{\zeta_p(1)}{\zeta_p(2)}$$

for instance. The product over the places $p$ does not converge since $\zeta_F$ admits a pole at $1$. I would like to regularize the product such in order to give a value to it. Morally, dividing by $\zeta_p(1)$ and multiplying by it would do the job and allow to consider
$$\zeta_F^\star(1)\prod_p \zeta_p(1)^{-1} x_p$$

where $\zeta_F^\star(1)$ denotes the residue at one. What is the relation between the residue at $1$ and the product of the local values at $1$, so that the value above could "replace" the product of the $x_p$?

Can I say that the value above is locally equal to $x_p$ (is that true?), hence could replace it in the whole product?

Comment: What is $\zeta_p$?

Comment: @LiorBary-Soroker It is the Dedekind zeta function attached to $F_p$.

Comment: So $\zeta_\mathfrak{p}(s) = \frac{1}{1-N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}}$. Regularize by dividing $\frac{1}{1-N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}}$ by $\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ ?